# Wifi disabled after time

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, internet-connection, ics

I do have several computers in my office, and unfortunately, the network admin has yet to patch my cables (which I'm not allowed to). So far, I'm stuck with Wifi, so I configured one of my Windows 8 computers with ICS on the Wifi-module and route the rest of the computers through that one.

However, Windows seems to drop the wifi-connection and therefore kill internet access on two occasions: if I lock the computer and if the computer is inactive for some time.

For the first problem (wifi drop on locking the screen), I have not found any information whatsoever.

All I found so far are hints on the power settings, where the wifi can be deactivated if the computer progresses into power saving mode - I did change that without effect on the problem. According to [some websites](https://icnerd.com/2013/03/04/fix-windows-8-laptop-dropping-wifi-connection-constantly/), this problem is quite known, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Any hints?

Comment: Uncheck the box “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power” present in the power management of the wifi properties

Comment: Nope, it's still going offline.